# Why isn't there a spacing between heading h1 and nav after using a float?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am currently facing an **issue related to using float** on the heading h1 and the navigation bar. I have applied float: left to both elements, expecting them to be aligned side by side with some spacing in between. However, I have noticed that there is no space between them, which is causing the design to look cluttered. I am perplexed as to why this is happening, despite having applied the appropriate CSS property. Could you please help me understand the reason behind this unexpected behavior?

```
h1 {
  float: left;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
```

[float error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUx2V.png)

Despite thoroughly examining the code and utilizing classes and ids, the issue with the lack of spacing between the h1 and nav elements, despite applying float:left to both, remains unresolved. One would expect the elements to be naturally spaced out with this property, but unfortunately, that's not the case. This has left me scratching my head and seeking out alternative solutions to create the desired layout.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float. Tip: don't use float for layout purpose, take a look to flexbox or grid

Comment: What are "the appropriate CSS [properties]" that you expect to work? Can you show a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score -1):

Is that all the code of both of them? You can play with the "width" and "margin", such as:

```
h1 {
  float: left;
  width:30%;
  margin-right:10%;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  width:60%;
}
```

Comment: You should not play with hardcoded widths as they will change on different screen sizes. As a matter of fact, using `float` is the wrong approach to start with.

Comment: I am not doing this as a real-time project but rather a dummy project for my learning. I already know that float layouts aren't used much nowadays but here the problem is that auto space should have been allocated rather than specifying paddings, margins e.t.c

Comment: that's why you should use flexbox with `justify-content: space-between`